# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cffi>=0.6 (from weasyprint->-

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

This error happens when i try to install `WeasyPrint` using PIP install from the offline packages folder I've created using `pip download`

```
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cffi>=0.6 (from weasyprint->-r requirements.txt (line 13)) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cffi>=0.6 (from weasyprint->-r requirements.txt (line 13))
```

all the packages are downloaded when i was on an online machine using `pip download -r requirements.txt -d folder_name`  then on the offline machine am using `pip install --no-index --find-links=folder_name -r requirements.txt` everything goes fine but not the `WeasyPrint` part ,, here is my requirements.txt :

```
django
psycopg2
six
openpyxl
python-dateutil
tablib
diff-match-patch
messytables
pytest-runner
setuptools-scm
lxml
setuptools-scm
weasyprint
Pyphen
```

Any help with that ?

Comment: `pip3 download weasyprint` downloads `cffi` 1.14 for me. Check if it downloaded one for you. Verify you transferred all downloaded files to the offline host.

Comment: yes it is downloaded with every other dependencies needed by weasyprint , but when i run the pip install it gives me the error , it is like weasyprint is not looking in the same folder .

Comment: Most probably the arches differ - run `python -c "from pip._internal.pep425tags import get_supported(); print(get_supported()[0])` on both machines and check whether the output is the same.